# How to remove arrow from React TextField Select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I am using TextField Select for dropdown.
Tried using "components={{ DropdownIndicator:() => null}}" on select, but did not work.

```
        <TextField disabled={true}                           
           label="itemNo"
           value={currentItem.itemNo}
           variant="outlined"
           InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontSize: 18, color: 'grey', backgroundColor: 'white', fontFamily: "monospace" }, shrink: true }}
           select
         >
                {this.state.itemNo && this.state.itemNo.map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem style={{ fontSize: 14, fontFamily: "monospace" }} key={item.key} value={item.id}>
                        {item.key}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
       </TextField>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For removing the select dropdown icon you will have to pass `IconComponent: () => null` in `SelectProps`, Props applied to the Select element. it accepts an object of the select elements props

for more information about `select`'s props https://material-ui.com/api/select/

Here is the working example https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-frost-g4s52?file=/src/App.js

```
<TextField disabled={true}                           
           label="itemNo"
           value={currentItem.itemNo}
           variant="outlined"
           InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontSize: 18, color: 'grey', backgroundColor: 'white', fontFamily: "monospace" }, shrink: true }}
           select
          // for passing props in select component
           SelectProps={{ IconComponent: () => null }}
         >
                {this.state.itemNo && this.state.itemNo.map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem style={{ fontSize: 14, fontFamily: "monospace" }} key={item.key} value={item.id}>
                        {item.key}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
       </TextField>
```

Comment: Okay, so please accepts this answer as correct

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer - it is helpful. I am having a hard time trying to find how to apply custom styling to the arrow? For example I'm just trying to scoot it to the left 25 pixels or so.